# If I train a custom tokenizer on my dataset, I would still be able to leverage a pre-trained model weight

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, mlmodel

This is a declaration, but I'm not sure it is correct. I can elaborate.

I have a considerably large dataset (23Gb). I'd like to pre-train the Roberta-base or XLM-Roberta-base, so my language model would fit better to be used in further downstream tasks.

I know I can just run it against my dataset for a few epochs and get good results. But, what if I also train the tokenizer to generate a new vocab, and merge files? The weights from the pre-trained model I started from will still be used, or the new set of tokens will demand complete training from scratch?

I'm asking this because maybe some layers can still contribute with knowledge, so the final model will have the better of both worlds: A tokenizer that fits my dataset, and the weights from previous training.

That makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short no.

You cannot use your own pretrained tokenizer for a pretrained model. The reason is that the vocabulary for your tokenizer and the vocabulary of the tokenizer that was used to pretrain the model that later you will use it as pretrained model are different. Thus a word-piece token which is present in Tokenizers's vocabulary may not be present in pretrained model's vocabulary.

Detailed answers can be found [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/8160),

Comment: thanks for taking your time on this. That makes sense.